# Помогите разобраться с сокращением кода сортировки

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

я старательно изучаю Python, в данный момент пытаюсь понять некоторые алгоритмы.

В книге вычитал вот такой вот код сортировки:

```
       def fin_more(seq):  # [8,5,6,2,10]
           mini = seq[0]
           mini_val = 0
           for i in range(1, len(seq)):
               if seq[i] < mini:
                   mini = seq[i]
                   mini_val = i 
           return mini_val

       def read(seq):
           new_list = []
           for j in range(len(seq)):
               mini = fin_more(seq)
               new_list.append(seq.pop(mini))
       return new_list

       print(read([8, 5, 6, 2, 10]))
```

Вот я и подумал: 
А почему так много строчек кода, если можно все уместить вот так:

```
       def prints(source):
           new_arr = list()
           new_arr.append(sorted(source))
           return print(*new_arr)
       prints([8, 5, 6, 2, 10])
```

Не могли бы Вы помочь мне понять конкретно пример из книги, и можно ли мне использовать свой вариант?

Comment: В вашем "сокращенном" варианте внутри функции `sorted` скрыта примерно такая же функция как в первом варианте, только написанная не на Python, а на Си (и другой, более оптимальный чем сортировка пузырьком алгоритм). Если вместо написания алгоритма вы будете использовать готовую функцию сортировки - то весь смысл теряется. Никаких алгоритмов вы так не изучите.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А не могли ли вы бы мне помочь разобраться с первой функции алгоритма. Так и не понял что именно она выполняет и как переносит результат во вторую функцию?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4

Comment: По поводу функций - во второй функции есть вызов первой функции, результат помещается в переменную `mini`. Так и переносится.

Comment: И еще, в вашем варианте `return print(*new_arr)` не имеет смысла, т.к. функция `print` возвращает `None`. Если нужно вывести результат, сделайте просто `print(*new_arr)`.

Comment: @insolor"Результат помещается в переменную mini" - то есть функция выполняется много раз пока все значения mini не уместятся во второй функции? Касательно  return print(*new arr) все понял,  спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем "сокращенном" варианте внутри функции sorted скрыта примерно такая же функция как в первом варианте, только написанная не на Python, а на Си (и другой, более оптимальный алгоритм). Если вместо написания алгоритма вы будете использовать готовую функцию сортировки - то весь смысл теряется. Никаких алгоритмов вы так не изучите.

В данном случае у вас сортировка [методом выбора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC):

Функция `fin_more` находит в исходном списке самый меньший элемент и возвращает его индекс. Вызывающая функция убирает (метод `pop`) из исходного списка этот найденный элемент и добавляет (`append`) его в другой список. Потом все повторяется, и так пока в исходном списке ничего не останется, а в `new_list` получится готовый отсортированный по возрастанию список.

Answer (score 4):

*На ответ не хватит,  но комментарии писать пока не могу.*

Пример из книги - это именно реализация алгоритма сортировки.  Ваш код  выполняет сортировку, но не реализует алгоритм сортировки,  а использует готовый,  кем-то реализованный алгоритм.